# Oracle Cloud free tier - Internal Server Error, HTTP Status Code: 500

Tags: apex

I am using Oracle Cloud free tier, I developed a small Oracle APEX application and using it from last 2-3 years, its was working fine.

suddenly I started receiving subject error "Internal Server Error, HTTP Status Code: 500", I can login to the application successfully but when I navigate from Report to any Form by clicking Edit link on report, I am getting error.
Internal Server Error,
HTTP Status Code: 500
Request ID: 904e0aa81173f03983bba0c65134e449
Request Timestamp: 2024-02-08T05:41:52.549748Z

Same error I am getting when I try to login to APEX as an Admin or Workspace user.

Can any one please guide and help.

Regards,
Ahmad

After Login unable to navigate to Oracle APEX application at Oracle APEX cloud free tier, autonomous database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The root cause of the problem is the sysaux scheme.

Related forum issue;

[Space Usage in container is too high on ATP DB](https://community.oracle.com/customerconnect/discussion/701487/space-usage-in-container-is-too-high-on-atp-db#latest)